# Can't created a boost::shared_ptr from this

Tags: c++, templates, boost, shared-ptr, explicit

Say I have the following abstract Class A. Now I'm trying to create a shared_ptr to A from inside Class A. So in A i have the following function:

```
class A {
    void A::setupArguments() const {
            ext::shared_ptr<A> ptr = ext::shared_ptr<A>(this);
        }
}
```

When compiling, it gives the error

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'Y *' to 'A *
```

when the shared_ptr function is defined as:

```
template<class Y>
explicit shared_ptr( Y * p ): px( p ), pn() // Y must be complete
{
   boost::detail::sp_pointer_construct( this, p, pn );
 }
```

I have read in another post that this has something to do with the shared_ptr function being explicit, where the the argument p must be strictly of type Y*. In this case, Y refers to Class A so by passing in "this", isnt "this" already explicit enough since its of type A*? I know the solution is to use std::enable_shared_from_this but I just want to understand why this would not work. For example, if we do the following, it would work

```
ext::shared_ptr<A>(new A())
```

But doesn't new A() return the same type as "this"?(both returns pointer to A) So why does new work but not "this"?

Comment: This is a bad idea. You can't hand over ownership of `*this` to a `shared_ptr`; it would make its actual owner pretty miffed.

Comment: `ext::shared_ptr<A>(this);` can never be correct. You can't create a shared pointer to a random pointer and expect it to work properly. You should use `enabled_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @SergeyA It's extremely rarely correct, and a big code smell even if it is, but *never* is not accurate. It's absolutely possible to perform ownership transfer this way under certain circumstances, (interoperating with certain asynchronous C libraries comes to mind).

Comment: @Frank this is never correct code :) Under very narrow circumstances the operation might be valid :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `setupArguments` is a `const`-qualified function, `this` is of type `const A*`. And `const A*` is not convertible to `A*` so it fails to compile.

You would need to use `shared_ptr<const A>` or remove the `const` qualifier.

The full error given should look like:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Y *' to 'A *'
        with
        [
            Y=const A
        ]
note: Conversion loses qualifiers
```

---

OT: be careful with constructing a `shared_ptr` from `this`, as it may lead to double deletes. Consider using `boost::enable_shared_from_this`

Comment: This answer should be reverted topside-down. Any suggestion on make code compilable is not applicable here, as it is an awful code. Instead, the answer should focus on proper usage of `enable_shared_from_this`, as it mentions in the end.

Comment: @Artyer this is a bit of a tricky one. Your answer is "technically" correct in the strictest sense of the word in that it answers the question OP has asked. However, it's patently obvious that if OP were to integrate it in their code, it would lead to Undefined Behavior and a broken program. You really need to qualify your answer with this information for it to be a "good" answer.

Comment: @Frank It doesn't always lead to undefined behaviour (for example, `(new A)->setupArguments()`, or passing a deleter that doesn't call `delete`). Though it's not the most common, and more likely to be wrong than not, it still might be called for

Comment: I actually tried changing to shared_ptr<const A> but got another error
Error C2440 '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'boost::shared_ptr<const A>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<A>

Comment: @LewWeiHao Wherever you've used `shared_ptr<A>` you would have to change to `shared_ptr<const A>`. Or you can make it a non-const function instead and continue using `shared_ptr<A>`